# Active form in a Windows application?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-1.1

I am developing a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application.
I have four forms which is inherited from Baseform in another project.
In all four forms I am using a label to show some transaction count based on network status. I have implemented a thread which gets the active form of application and setting up the text. The code works fine if application screen is active. If I minimize and open any other application, I am getting an null error exception.

How do I get the active form of an application?

```
Private Sub StartThread() 
    pollThread =New Thread(AddressOf PollfileStatus) 
    pollThread.IsBackground =True
    running =True
    pollThread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub PollfileStatus() 
    While (running)
        Try
            For Each e As Control In Me.ActiveForm.Controls 
                If (e.Name = "pbStatus") Then
                    e.Invoke(New SetTextCallback(AddressOf Settext), 
                        New Object() {e, 10}) 
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception 
            Throw New ApplicationException(ex.Message) 
        End Try
        Thread.Sleep(6000)
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: (Updated my answer based on your comment)

Answer (score 3):

Understandably Me.ActiveForm is empty, since minimizing your form makes it inactive. You have two options:

- Test if Me.ActiveForm is empty, and if so, do not update the label. This will effectively 'pause' label updates, until the user restores the window again.
- Create a property on your class that contains your thread, to pass a reference of the form you have to update. This way the label on the given form will update even if it is not the active form. This might be a better option, it will update even if the form is inactive in the background, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the [`Application.OpenForms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) shared property. It contains a collection of all forms in your application.

**EDIT**: Since you're working with .net 1.1 and don't have access to `Application.OpenForms`, here are some suggestions:

- Implement your own shared class (module) that contains an `ArrayList` of forms. You could then create a base class inheriting from `Form`, handle the `Load` event to add the current form to the list of forms and the `Closed` event to remove it. Once you have that class, have all your *real* forms derive from it. BTW, it's (almost) how it is done in .Net 2.0.
- Turn the problem around and have the working thread raise events when the values change that you can handle in each form to update it.

Comment: Hi Julien Poulin ,
But i am using .net 1.1 frame work where Application.OpenForms is not supported

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but I'd thought I'd offer a suggestion as well: you could implement a `Public Shared CurrentForm As Form` that you set in the `Form.Activated` event of a base form class all your forms inherit from. From the thread you could then use `CurrentForm` to access the desired form.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy like this in vb.net

```
Dim MYFormName As String = Me.Name.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many solutions for this situation:

- first of all you should consider checking if the current form is null before proceeding in any action.
- second: if that condition passes, a good approach to store the last active form's reference.

Answer (score 0):

This might work but I cannot test it right now.

```
For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
    If frm.ContainsFocus Then
        Return frm
    End If
Next
```